# Understanding the instruments

Tags: xcode, instruments

I have observed the VM Tracker the instruments, but I can not understand some informations.

For example:

What is Dirty Size, MALLOC_TINY, MALLOC_LARGE and Memory Tag 70?
If possible, how can I release Dirty Size?

[image]

Could anyone help me, or show me the documentation where I can better understand this informations?

Answer (score 0):

The following article explains dirty sizes:

[Tracking background memory usage of iOS 4 apps](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/5/tracking-background-memory-usage-of-ios-4-apps.html)

The VM Tracker instrument displays the virtual memory map of your application. MALLOC_TINY, MALLOC_LARGE and Memory Tag 70 are types of memory regions. A MALLOC_TINY region is a writable memory region that contains small memory allocations, allocations 512 bytes and smaller. The VM Tracker instrument is very similar to the vmmap command-line tool. Searching for information on vmmap can lead you to information on the different types of memory regions.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I can release dirty size?

Comment: When you say "release dirty size", are you asking how to reduce the dirty size of your app? If so, I can't tell you because I don't have your source code. The Allocations instrument can help you find where your app allocates memory.

Comment: I have used instruments, but did't found leak. So i would like to  understand of the variables cited above better.